# Retrieve drools working memory from Optaplanner solution

Tags: drools, optaplanner, drools-guvnor, drools-planner

When drl file used while solving constraints one could use `insertLogical()` which insert facts in drools working memory only and may not be retracted till completion of solution(LHS stay true forever for that `insertLogical()`). When we get solution from Optaplanner's `solver.solve()`, we receive our own solution classes option like NurseRoster, CloudBalance. But how could I retrieve facts which stayed in Drools working memory till my solution stayed so I can see what caused solution?

I'm looking for something like:

```
solver.solve(nurseRoster);
scoreDirector.getDroolsWorkingMemory().getNotRetractedFacts()
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The working memory is not avialable after solution has been processed, however use `scoreDirector` in this way to retrieve it from an active session:

```
    solver.getScoreDirectorFactory().buildScoreDirector()    
    director=(DroolsScoreDirector<Solution>)((DefaultSolver)solver).getSolverScope().getScoreDirector();
    LegacyDroolsScoreDirectorFactory<TaskPlanningSolution> scoreDirectorFactory = (LegacyDroolsScoreDirectorFactory)director.getScoreDirectorFactory();
    KnowledgeBaseImpl kbase=(KnowledgeBaseImpl)scoreDirectorFactory.getKieBase();//.newKieSession();
    InternalWorkingMemory internalWorkingMemory =((StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl)kbase.getWorkingMemories()[0]).getInternalWorkingMemory();
```