# OptaPlanner Understanding a rule

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, optaplanner

We have below rule in our rule file, I am trying to understand the LHS part of the rule, there are two lines RoomAssignment and Schedule. Can someone explain how it evaluates to? An AND or OR operator is used between  RoomAssignment and Schedule?

```
Rule "Test"
when
        RoomAssignment(schedule.isFixed == true, startingTimeGrain != null, room != null, manager != null, $startingTimeGrainIndex : startingTimeGrainIndex, $room: room, $manager: manager, $schedule: schedule)
        Schedule(id == $schedule.id, fixedDateTime == true, startTimeGrainIndex != $startingTimeGrainIndex)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -100000);

        end
```

Answer (score 1):

A logical `and` is implicit between patterns. Working Memory must contain (at least) one RoomAssignment and (at least) one Schedule object with suitable field values. The rule fires once for each matching combination of fact objects.

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest how to debug the rule firing ? and working memory objects please?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46703743/retrieve-drools-working-memory-from-optaplanner-solution